# Google pie chart not showing tool tip on hover in the blazor server application

Tags: blazor, google-visualization, blazor-server-side

Google pie chart not showing tool tip on hover in the blazor server application. I have used a sample code provided in the documentation link(https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart). If I paste full code on a normal HTML file it will work. I have created a new sample application but still it is not working. If we click on the chart then it will show. I want the tooltip to show by hover, I have tried trigger, isHtml options also.
Please help me.

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['Work',     11],
      ['Eat',      2],
      ['Commute',  2],
      ['Watch TV', 2],
      ['Sleep',    7]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'My Daily Activities'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few troubleshooting steps to get you started.

##### 1. Check Script Order

Ensure Google Charts script is loaded before your Blazor script.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="_content/BlazorApp/script.js"></script>
```

##### 2. Use `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback`

Wrap your chart initialization code inside `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback`.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  // Your chart code here
}
```

##### 3. Tooltip Options

Explicitly set tooltip trigger to `'focus'` or `'selection'`.

```js
var options = {
  title: 'My Daily Activities',
  tooltip: { trigger: 'focus' }  // or 'selection'
};
```

##### 4. Blazor Interop

If you're calling JS from Blazor, make sure you're using `IJSRuntime` correctly.

```cs
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

@code {
  private async Task DrawChart() {
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("drawChart");
  }
}
```

##### 5. Check CSS

Make sure no CSS is interfering with tooltips.

##### 6. Debug

Use browser's developer tools to debug JS errors.

##### 7. Blazor Prerendering

If using prerendering, make sure to initialize the chart after the component is fully rendered.

```
csharp
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
  if (firstRender)
  {
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("drawChart");
  }
}
```